# Debian linux server upload speed is limited for one connection but not multiple

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

Ok..I have a server that is running Debian linux, opensshd, vsftpd. This server has a 1Gb upload pipe, and my clients pipe is 2.5mb downstream.

The issue is that I can download something from that server to my client, through any of rsync, scp, or filezilla ftp..or anything. My download speed only sees about 1/3rd of what it should. However, if I use DownThemAll or something else which uses multiple simultaneous connections, then I get all the speed I want.

My provider assures me (and he's technically knowledgeable/savvy), that it isn't anything on their end..that they don't have any caps on that.

What's going on here? It's kind of unnerving because I can't just rsync it over which would be preferable.

Comment: Most likely, somewhere between the two machines there is a link that is maxed out. By using multiple connections, you get more "shares" of that link. A `traceroute` might help locate the bottleneck.